# change background color of a specific Row asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, aspxgridview

I need a hand.

How to change background color of a  entire Row on dataBound Event Programatically in a gridview ?

```
 protected void databound_gridview(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {


  }
```

Comment: Are you going to change the colour of the row depending on a condition?

Comment: No condition at all.
Just a second row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of my head you'll need to create a [RowDataBound Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then you can do something like

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex == 1)
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..
easier than i thought